# Django admin actions: generate actions for all choices with only one method

Tags: python, django

For a model that looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(choices=FIELD_CHOICES)
```

where

```
FIELD_CHOICES = [("Update this", "Update this"),
                 ("Update that", "Update that"), 
                 ("Update something else", "Update something else"), ]
```

and with the following admin view

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["user", ]
```

If we want to have an action to update the field with any of its values, we add one method for each value in the ModelAdminView, like so:

```
    actions = ("update_this", "update_that", "update_something_else")

    def update_this(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(my_field="Update this")

    def update_that(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(my_field="Update that")

    def update_something_else(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(my_field="Update something else")
```

However, all these methods are identical, except some parts that could be retrieved from the field's choices...

Does Django provide any way to generate actions for all choices of a field with only one generic method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do stuff like this with the Django admin. I typically achieve this by subclassing the [`get_actions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_actions) method of Django's `ModelAdmin` class. Here's an example that might not be *exactly* what you're looking for, but should at least illustrate a method to dynamically create an arbitrary number of bulk actions that basically do the same thing:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    _update_fields = (
        # ('Text for the dropdown', 'a_unique_function_name', 'some value')
        ('This', 'function_name_for_this', 'this value'),
        ('That', 'function_name_for_that', 'that value'),
        ('Other Thing', 'function_name_for_other_thing', 'some other value'),
    )

    def get_actions(self, request):
        def func_maker(value):
            # this function will be your update function, just mimic the traditional bulk update function
            def update_func(self, request, queryset):
                queryset.update(my_field=value)
            return update_func

        # check out django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.get_actions for more details - basically it
        # just returns an ordered dict, keyed by your action name, with a tuple of the function, a name,
        # and a description for the dropdown.
        # Python 2.7-style:
        actions = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        # If using Python 3, call it like so:
        # actions = super().get_actions(request)

        # You can just tack your own values/actions onto it like so:
        for description, function_name, value in self._update_fields:
            func = func_maker(value)
            name = 'update_{}'.format(function_name)
            actions['update_{}'.format(function_name)] = (func, name, 'Update {}'.format(description))

        return actions
```

Comment: NOTE: You might want to control permissions for these actions. For example, you can wrap the `for` loop in `if self.has_change_permission(request): ...`